# Touchpad not working on VAIO VGN-TZ170N

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad, vaio

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my VAIO VGN-TZ170N and the touchpad isn't working.

Tried an external USB mouse and that isn't working either.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I attached to a wired connection and reboot and tried installing the drivers which were available and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried the following solution, it seems OK now, hopefully for you too (I have a VAIO VGN also):

- [Keyboard and touch pad is not working on a Dell XPS 15z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127950/keyboard-and-touch-pad-is-not-working-on-a-dell-xps-15z)