#  Keyboard and touch pad is not working on a Dell XPS 15z

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, dell

I am new linux user, I dont anything about how linux works, i am working on that, but mean while, i installed ubuntu on my Dell xps 15z, it works fine, except for the keyboard and the touch pad mouse. I searched for the solution but no success, please anyone have solution for this, I am very excited about linux, it very beautiful, very user friendly, I want to replace my windows with it.

Ps. Please be specific in your answer 'couse i dont know anything about linux, keep in my I am a very new user.

Answer (score 1):

I have a XPS 15z too and I will tell you what I did on my xps. First, about the keyboard i don't know what happend with yours, on my notebook it works very well, i think that you will have to reinstall ubuntu to fix this.
But for the touchpad has a simple solution, you will open the terminal (ctrl+alt+T), type `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and edit the file wich opened. Before the line `exit 0` you will add the following lines:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Save the file and reboot the computer, i believe after this the touchpad will work. Another thing is about the videocard, it not works in ubuntu, i try so many solutions but anyone works.

I hope i could help you, sorry about my "english', its not my native language.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I tried this but no luck, may be it is a problem with my installation, I will try reinstallation, hope it orks this time.

Comment: I just reinstalled Ubuntu, and applied your commands, now it is not working, but when I close the laptops lid and open it after a while, the touch pad and the keyboard will work, I don't know what is the problem, but right now it is better than nothing, if you know how to fix this i will appreciate it, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I've got DELL XPS 15z too, and I just installed ubuntu 12.04.

About videocard, I install Bumblebee with this commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

Then, I reloaded with :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Just to be sure the system was up to date, and I installed :

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

One more thing to do :

```
sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

Where $USER is your username. This is to allow you to choose the videocard later.
Now restart your laptop, and enjoy ! To test it, that's very simple : try this to command lines :

```
glxspheres
optirun glxspheres
```

And see ! for me in the first case I have 1 to 2 fps, and in the second case I have more than 150 fps. So if you need to use the nvidia card, just add "optirun" at the beginnin of your software launcher.

Answer (score 0):

About keyboard and touchpad, I had the same problem you have, I mean : keyboard was working on grub loading page, but not after, on the login shell, and the touchpad was not working too. It take 5 minutes to do it.

I solve the problem by adding acpi=noirq at the end of the boot line.

The way I did the modifications was this :

1/ During the first boot, I press [e] when I was on the grub loading page, then I gone to the begin of the last line and I came back by the left arrow. Then I just added there :

```
acpi=noirq
```

But take care, maybe you have qwerty keyboard instead  of azerty one (like me) so press [q] instead of [a]...

Then, press [ctrl]+[x] to execute this command line.

2/ Now you should be able to log in.

3/ To keep this modification once for all, you should edit the grub command. Execute this in a terminal :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And modify the line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

It to obtain this line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
```

Then, save, close, and back in the terminal, execute :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now restart your computer, and all should be great... See above my post for the videocard... Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

When i was using ubuntu 11.10 i did almost like this you did. Now on 12.04 i didin't do anything yet, i'm still look for something wich make my HDMI works, did your HDMI work?
When i using 11.10 i found the solution on post #118 of this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1776254&page=12
an then i turned off my videocard, as it did not work, at least the autonomy of my battery increased double.

Thanks man

Comment: HDMI is not working for me as well, but actually I do not need that, but you can use an adapter for the mini-HDMI to HDMI, it will be working that way, I did not try this but I so it some where, I do not remember.

Answer (score 0):

May this help you, open your terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

updating the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux"
```

Don't forget to save and close, go back in the terminal run `sudo update-grub`

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1014240)