# Problem with ubuntu 12.04 - dell xps 15z - keyboard, trackpad, graphic card

Tags: drivers, boot, keyboard

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04, and it doesnt recognize any additional drivers, the keyboards does not work nor does the trackpad nor does it recognize the graphic card. How can i solve this problems?

Also sometimes it crashes during the booting.

any suggestions?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same keyboard and trackpad issue on the same laptop.
Solved booting problem adding acpi=off noveau.modeset=0 at start.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you add the line?

In my case, trackpad works but no additional drivers are recognized as well. (precision nvidia M1000)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this other post:

[Keyboard and touch pad is not working on a Dell XPS 15z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127950/keyboard-and-touch-pad-is-not-working-on-a-dell-xps-15z/128228#128228)

In there we are talking about al this issues.